# Haskel types mismatching - data type

Tags: haskell

Sorry if this is stupid question - I am constantly getting error and can not figure it out.
My code below:

```
data Health = Health [String]

let health = Health ["<3","<3","<3"]

showHealth :: [Health] -> String 
showHealth [] = ""
showHealth (x:xs) = "" ++ (showSingleHealth x) ++ (showHealth xs)


showSingleHealth :: Health -> String 
showSingleHealth (Health point) = point
```

And error I am getting is on "showSingleHealth", error say - Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: [String]
    . In the expression: point
      In an equation for ‘showSingleHealth’:
          showSingleHealth (Health point) = point

Comment: Remove the `let`. This is used in a `do` block, or in an expression with `let ... in ...`, but not in a declaration.

Comment: It is used in a do, it's a small game that I am trying to implement, just dragged code parts for this exact part that I am having issue with :)

Comment: The pattern `Health point` binds `point` to a *list* of `String`s, not a single `String`. What is `showSingleHealth heath` supposed to return? What argument do you intend to pass to `showHealth`? I wonder if all you really want is `showHealth = concat`, to turn `["<3", "<3", "<3"]` into `"<3<3<3"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `let`. A `let` is used in a `do` block, and a `let … in …` in an *expression*, but not in a *declaration*.

You thus can implement this with:

```
data Health = Health [String]

health = Health ["<3","<3","<3"]

showHealth :: [Health] -> String 
showHealth [] = ""
showHealth (x:xs) = "" ++ (showSingleHealth x) ++ (showHealth xs)


showSingleHealth :: Health -> String 
showSingleHealth (Health point) = point
```

But this does not resolve all the problems, since `showSingleHealth` should return a `String`, but `point` is a *list* of strings. You thus can for example concatenate the health items with [**`concat :: Foldable f => f [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concat):

```
showSingleHealth :: Health -> String
showSingleHealth (Health point) = concat point
```

Finally `showHealth` can be implemented in a more clean manner with [**`concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap):

```
showHealth :: [Health] -> String 
showHealth = concatMap showSingleHealth
```

That being said, it might make more sense to let `Health` only wrap a *single* `String`, not a *list* of `String`s, or even better, an `Int` for example, and repeat a string part with [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate).